# Split a comma delimited string which may contain commas and escaped quotes between single quotes

Tags: python, regex, csv

How do you split a comma delimiter string. The string is a series of comma delimited numbers and words. Words are quoted with single quotes and numbers are not. Words may contain non-delimiting commas which should be fine inside quotes. Words may contain other kinds of quotes which must be escaped by a preceding backslash like so:

```
'','some-mail@some-domain.org','f4c1bfd5-969d-\'4,7\"2a-,b1\'29-42de49eb4406',2827,1378614418
```

I have tried to use a regex `[^\']` to split but that also picks up escaped commas.

I have tried literally counting the characters as an alternative but that is deathly slow.

Also python's `csv` reader splits the string on the non-delimiting commas if there are escaped slashes in the string. Perhaps it's not valid CSV?

The sub-string list I should have as a result is:

```
[ 
'', # empty string
'some-mail@some-domain.org', # text like email
'f4c1bfd5-969d-\'4,7\"2a-,b1\'29-42de49eb4406', # text, comma and escaped quotes
2827, # number
1378614418 # number
]
```

This is how I have used the csv module:

```
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(values_string), delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True)
```

But I get:

```
['', 'some-mail@some-domain.org', 'f4c1bfd5-969d-\\4', '7\\"2a-', "b1\\'29-42de49eb4406'", '2827', '1378614418']
```

Comment: Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library with the appropriate dialect and/or formatting parameters. It seems like you could use the defaults but change the quote char from `"` to `'`.

Comment: @Blurp - The csv reader splits across the commas in quotes if they contain escaped quotes

Comment: Not if you set the options correctly

Comment: What is the source of this data and how are you reading it in?

Comment: I have included a snippet of how I have parsed with the csv module. If I don't have the right options, please enlighten me.

Comment: It's a custom dump of some database for which I do not have the access to change the format from the source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open(file_name) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, quotechar="'", doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
```